# Matplotlib colorbar labels to fit into boxes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I created a scatter plot using `matplotlib` but I am somehow unable to get the labels to center into the boxes within the `colorbar`..

This is the code I have so far:

```
cMap = ListedColormap(['Orange', 'Purple', 'Blue','Red','Green'])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.figure(figsize=(12,12),dpi = 80)

#data
dist = np.random.rand(1900,1900)

#legend
cbar = plt.colorbar(scatter)

cbar.ax.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
for j, lab in enumerate(['$Training$','$None$','$GS$','$ML$','$Both$']):
    cbar.ax.text( .5, j - .985, lab, ha='left', va='center', rotation = 270)
cbar.ax.get_yaxis().labelpad = 15
cbar.ax.set_ylabel('Outliers', rotation=270)

indices = np.where(outlier_label != -2)[0]
plt.scatter(dist[indices, 0], dist[indices, 1], c=outlier_label[indices], cmap=cMap, s=20)
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')
plt.title('Projection of the data', fontsize=24)
```

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Please, share a reproducible code example. There are missing variables in your code...

Answer (score 0):

In line  `cbar.ax.text( .5, j - .985, lab, ha='left', va='center', rotation = 270)` you have to work and change with '.985' with try and error to get better results.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the y limits of the colorbar to know its top and bottom.  Dividing that area into 11 equally spaced positions, will have the 5 centers at the odd positions of that list. Similarly, you can extract the x limits to find the horizontal center.

Some remarks:

- If you already called `plt.subplots()`, then `plt.figure()` will create a new figure, leaving the first plot empty.  You can set the `figsize` directly via `plt.subplots(figsize=...)`
- You are mixing matplotlib's ["object-oriented interface"](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/) with the pyplot interface.  This can lead to a lot of confusion. It is best to stick to one or the other. (The object-oriented interface is preferred, especially when you are creating non-trivial plots.)
- You set `dist = np.random.rand(1900,1900)` of dimensions `1900x1900` while you are only using dimensions `1900x2`.
- The code nor the text give an indication of the values inside `outlier_label`. The code below assumes they are 5 equally-spaced numbers, and that both the lowest and the highest value are present in the data.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import numpy as np

colors = ['Orange', 'Purple', 'Blue', 'Red', 'Green']
cmap = ListedColormap(colors)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 12), dpi=80)

# data
dist = np.random.randn(1900, 2).cumsum(axis=0)

outlier_label = np.repeat(np.arange(5), 1900 // 5)

indices = outlier_label != -2
scatter = ax.scatter(dist[indices, 0], dist[indices, 1], c=outlier_label[indices], cmap=cmap, s=20)

# legend
cbar = plt.colorbar(scatter, ax=ax)

cbar.ax.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
cb_xmin, cb_xmax = cbar.ax.get_xlim()
cb_ymin, cb_ymax = cbar.ax.get_ylim()
num_colors = len(colors)
for j, lab in zip(np.linspace(cb_ymin, cb_ymax, 2 * num_colors + 1)[1::2],
                  ['$Training$', '$None$', '$GS$', '$ML$', '$Both$']):
     cbar.ax.text((cb_xmin + cb_xmax) / 2, j, lab, ha='center', va='center', rotation=270, color='white', fontsize=16)
cbar.ax.get_yaxis().labelpad = 25
cbar.ax.set_ylabel('Outliers', rotation=270, fontsize=18)

ax.set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')
ax.set_title('Projection of the data', fontsize=24)

plt.show()
```

[image: colorbar with labels at the centers]